# How to get parent component data from child window in angular 8 using window.opener

Tags: angular, window.open, window.opener

I have 2 pages in angular, page1 with a button, when clicked, it opens page2.
So they are 2 different components. I must use window.opener to get page1 data in page2 because i am calling `window.opener.page1Func()`

In pure html and javascript, i can get data from page1func defined in page1.

page1

```
function page1func()
{
    return "xxx";
}
```

page2

```
var result = window.opener.page1func();
```

above is working fine in pure js and html, but how can i do this in Angular way? (angular 8 is what i am using)

Any clue would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: angular is SPA. you can use routing in angular

Comment: Does routing works with a new window? I need to pass data from parent to child (pop up new window using window.open(page2)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to pass data from parent to child (pop up new window)

1. Defining "**window**" component that will be rendered on a new popup
   window .Here is a working example of [popup window component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window-jbwdf3?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)
2. ngrx-store
3. window.postMessage()
4. session/local storage